# Docker Swarm and load-balancing of Varnish persistent TCP connections (VIP)

Tags: varnish, docker-swarm

I have a Varnish HTTP cache running in front of 40 workers. These workers are running on two identical Docker nodes (`node-1` and `node-2`, 20 on each) as a unique service (`web_workers`). We're using Docker Swarm with the default `endpoint_mode`, which is round-robin load-balancing. So Varnish forwards requests to a unique backend hostname (= Docker Swarm Virtual IP as far as I understand).

Not long ago, I noticed that nodes were receiving an unequal load of requests: `node-1` processes 4 times more requests than `node-2`.

Varnish uses long-lived persistent TCP connections to the backend, and `node-2` was started after `node-1`. I suspect the difference of load can be explained by the fact that `node-1` was launched first, and the Docker Swarm naive round-robin load-balancing algorithm has just allocated persistent TCP connections to it before `node-2` started and now it looks like this imbalance is persisting since Varnish uses long-lived TCP connections.

1. How could I confirm this theory, if it makes sense?
2. What are the possible workarounds?

I'm thinking of disabling TCP connection reuse on Varnish side, but it could result in a severe performance hit (to be tested). Another option is to not use a unique Docker service but have one per physical node. I also could restart Varnish instances as soon as the Docker service is updated, but this is a sensitive piece of infrastructure I don't want to restart. Any idea is welcome!

EDIT:

Backend configuration part of the VCL file:

```
backend origin {
 .between_bytes_timeout = 5s;
 .connect_timeout = 1s;
 .first_byte_timeout = 5s;
 .host = "web_origin";
 .host_header = "web_origin";
 .max_connections = 200;
 .port = "8080";
 }

sub vcl_init {
    new origin_director = directors.round_robin();
    origin_director.add_backend(origin);
}
```

Comment: Please share your VCL file, so I can have a look at the current situation. Based on the VCL file, we can start thinking about possible scenarios and a solution to your problem. Don't hesitate to append the VCL file to your original question.

Comment: Added backend configuration, although I'm not sure to understand how it can help. Everything is going through a unique Docker Swarm VIP. Connection reuse is configured on Varnish side (default values), as shown in varnishstats (`BACKEND.backend_reuse` increases quickly)

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need to know about DNS resolution in Varnish is that it is done at compile team. This means that when your VCL file is loaded, Varnish will resolve the hostname and stick to the IP address.

If `web_origin` refers to multiple IP addresses, Varnish will only choose one. When the VCL is loaded again (because of a restart or an explicit VCL reload), the other IP might be used.

If you want to do round-robin loadbalancing in VCL, you'll need at least 2 origin servers. Here's an example:

```
vcl 4.1;

import directors;

backend origin1 {
 .between_bytes_timeout = 5s;
 .connect_timeout = 1s;
 .first_byte_timeout = 5s;
 .host = "web_origin";
 .host_header = "web_origin1";
 .max_connections = 200;
 .port = "8080";
}

backend origin2 {
 .between_bytes_timeout = 5s;
 .connect_timeout = 1s;
 .first_byte_timeout = 5s;
 .host = "web_origin";
 .host_header = "web_origin2";
 .max_connections = 200;
 .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_init {
    new origin_director = directors.round_robin();
    origin_director.add_backend(origin1);
    origin_director.add_backend(origin2);
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = origin_director.backend();
}
```

If the `web_origin` hostname only points to a single IP and you want to continue doing loadbalancing at the VIP level, you could consider reducing the value of the `[backend_idle_timeout][1]` runtime parameter.

However, if you want more control over the loadbalancing, it's best to do this in Varnish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is indeed only one origin server and this is because we let docker swarm perform load-balancing itself instead of relying on Varnish. Director is not needed here, I agree (it just happens that we used it before switching to a unique origin server's hostname).

Comment: Also it's hard to confirm the hypothesis because I can't figure out how often the persistent TCP connections are closed and reopened.